# Insert XML element in xml document using Ant

Tags: xml, ant, insert, xmltask

I want to insert one xml element in xml document :-

Input XML:-

```
    <cus:try xmlns:cus="http://www.abc.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xt="http://www.efg.com">
     <cus:trying>
  <cus:query>
  <xt:resourceTypes>abc</xt:resourceTypes>
  <xt:envValueTypes>def</xt:envValueTypes>
     </cus:query>
 </cus:trying>
    </cus:try>
```

Output XML:-

```
 <cus:try xmlns:cus="http://www.abc.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xt="http://www.efg.com">
     <cus:trying>
  <cus:query>
  <xt:resourceTypes>abc</xt:resourceTypes>
  <xt:resourceTypes>bcd</xt:resourceTypes>
  <xt:envValueTypes>def</xt:envValueTypes>
     </cus:query>
 </cus:trying>
    </cus:try>
```

That means i'm trying to insert one more  with namespaces. I need to insert exactly like this..

I'm trying below

```
   <xmltask source="abc.xml" dest="abc.xml">
<insert path="//*[local-name()='resourceTypes']"> <![CDATA[
        <xa:resourceTypes id="3"/>
        ]]>
    </insert>
    </xmltask>
```

However, it is failing.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `<insert>` to work, explicitly refer to the namespace in the element. Also `<insert>`, by default, puts new elements under existing ones. The code below changes the default to `after`.

```
<xmltask source="abc.xml" dest="abc.xml">
    <insert path="//*[local-name()='resourceTypes']" position="after"> <![CDATA[
        <xt:resourceTypes xmlns:xt="http://www.efg.com">bcd</xt:resourceTypes>
    ]]>
    </insert>
</xmltask>
```

The resulting XML, based on the XML in the question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<cus:try xmlns:cus="http://www.abc.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xt="http://www.efg.com">
  <cus:trying>
    <cus:query>
      <xt:resourceTypes>abc</xt:resourceTypes>
<xt:resourceTypes>bcd</xt:resourceTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>def</xt:envValueTypes>
    </cus:query>
  </cus:trying>
</cus:try>
```

Comment: However, it is adding like below:-                                                              <resourceTypes xmlns="http://www.efg.com">bcd</resourceTypes>  not in below way <xt:resourceTypes>bcd</xt:resourceTypes>

Comment: I've edited my answer. I've changed the CDATA section so it creates elements with the `xt` prefix.

Comment: Awsome. Thanks a million Chad Nouis :-)