# Ant xmltask adding a blank xmlns=""

Tags: xml, ant, xmltask

Below is the complete ant target which I am running to insert the driver to my wildfly standalone.xml:

```
<target name="xmlrewrite" >
    <!--Driver-->
    <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
    <xmltask source="standalone.xml" dest="standalone.xml" report="true">
        <copy path="//driver[@module='com.oracle.ojdbc6']/text()" property="modelexists"/>
        <insert
            path="*[local-name()='server']/*[local-name()='profile']/*[local-name()='subsystem'][3]/*[local-name()='datasources']/*[local-name()='drivers']" 
            unless="modelexists">
            <![CDATA[
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            ]]>
        </insert>
    </xmltask>
</target>
```

As per my understanding, the entry should be made in the standalone.xml only if it is not already present, since i am using `unless="modelexists"`.

But apparently it is making a new entry for oracle driver with an additional `xmlns=""`, which makes two entries of oracle and this causes my build to fail.

Please let me know if you would need any more info.

Comment: Can you edit the question update with it with full task, in the above you seemed to put in pieces. Also show the input xml that you working on.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem with the new entry for oracle driver with an additional `xmlns=""` you have to provide the namespace (found at the root element in the xml) for the node `driver` in the CDATA section:

```
<driver xmlns="namespace_for_this_xml" name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22534680)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `standalone.xml` file is related to JBoss. The XML elements in a JBoss `standalone.xml` are in XML namespaces. So, the `<copy>` element nested under `<xmltask>` will need to be namespace-aware:

```
<copy path="//*[local-name()='driver' and @module='com.oracle.ojdbc6']/text()" property="modelexists"/>
```