# Groovy - Adding node to existing XML file with echoxml

Tags: xml, groovy

I am trying to insert a node into an existing XML document.
I use groovy and ANT for that.

So does my XML look like:

```
<root>
 <node1 db="a" 
   user="test"/>
</root>
```

Within this XML file I have a groovy section that looks that way:

My groovy script, embedded in the ANT xml file.

```
<target name="some-target">
 <script language="groovy">
 def fragment = '''&lt;root&gt;
 &lt;node1 db=&quot;a&quot; 
   user=&quot;test&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/root&gt;''';

def parser = new XmlParser();
xml.appendNode{fragment};

def xmlOutput = new StringWriter();
def xmlNodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(xmlOutput));      
xmlNodePrinter.print(xml);
```

Now, I just want to add a second node, but I do not how to achieve that?

If I add now a second node I always get the following output in the result:

```
<root>
 <node1 db="a" 
   user="test"/>
   <Script1$_run_closure2@451001e5/>
</root>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the Ant task, you can do this in plain Groovy:

Assuming you have a file variable which points to your existing XML

```
def fileText = new File('/tmp/test.xml')
```

Then, you can do:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def fileText = new File('/tmp/test.xml')

def parser = new XmlParser()

def xml = parser.parse('/tmp/test.xml')

// Add a new node
xml.append(parser.parseText('<node2 db="c" user="test2"/>'))

// Write it out over the top of the original file
def xmlOutput = new StringWriter()
def xmlNodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(xmlOutput))
xmlNodePrinter.print(xml)
fileText.text = xmlOutput.toString()
```

#### Edit

Right, here's 2 methods to append a node.  I've put `xmltask.jar` in the same folder as the build. The first target uses xmltask, the second uses groovy.

I've also added `test.xml` to the same directory, and this is what is read-in, appended to and written out

```
<project name="Xml Foozling" basedir=".">

  <path id="runtime.path">
    <pathelement location="xmltask.jar"/>
  </path>

  <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" classpathref="runtime.path"/>

  <target name="insert-node-with-xml-task">
    <xmltask source="test.xml" dest="output-task.xml">
        <insert path="/root">
          <![CDATA[
          <node1 db="new"  user="hooray"/>
          ]]>
        </insert>
    </xmltask>
  </target>

  <target name="insert-node-with-groovy">
    <script language="groovy">
      <![CDATA[
      import groovy.xml.*

      new XmlParser().with { parser ->
        parser.parse('test.xml').with { xml ->
          xml.append(parser.parseText('<node2 db="new" user="hooray"/>'))
          new File('output-script.xml').withWriter { out ->
            new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(out)).print(xml)
          }
        }
      }
      ]]>
    </script>
  </target>

</project>
```

Fingers crossed

Comment: Thanks for your help! Well, I must do it with ANT, do have any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: I'll have a think 

Comment: Can you use xmltask? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514657/insert-xml-element-in-xml-document-using-ant

Comment: Well, I forgot to say that I had to escape the additional node in my script. If I use your groovy script now, I always get the following string into my XML: <Script1$_run_closure1@68c9133c/> - but not the new node, I think it has something to do with the escaping?

Comment: Why did you have to escape it?

Comment: grovvy is embedded in an xml file; this xml file has targets that I call. Furthermore, I use an XSD file to check the XML.As soon as I do not escape it, I always get an error like: script doesn't support the nested element.

Comment: Can you wrap it in a CDATA block instead of escaping it?

Comment: Hm, I have to lok it up. Have not ever worked with CDATA - blocks.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: Thanks, then I will try it this way, too. Sadly, that escaping the XML part reduced the errors but produced not what I expected. Would have solved quickly my problem but what I always get is: <Script1$_run_closure1@68c9133c/>  -- seems to be the memory address or wrong interpretation of my escaped string?

Comment: I tried it with CDATA but that also did not help since the output is always a valid XML with this before the closing root node: <Script1$_run_closure1@6caf0677/> - I think I have to find a way to reverse the escaping string. It could be everything done in groovy, so that would not be a problem although I said before that it has to be done in ANT.

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution would be to delete the root node at the end of the file and past from an extra file the missing node into this file?

Comment: Can you change the question so it shows a complete example that I can run and see the problem? I'm a bit lost at the moment ☹️

Comment: Added to the answer... Fingers crossed, not used Ant for about 6 years but it seems to work ;-)

Comment: Hi, it works great. I used the xmltask variant! How can I thank you? Thousand thanks!!!!!

Comment: Yay! No worries :-)  Don't forget to help someone when they're stuck in the future :-)

Comment: Sure, never had the idea of not helping someone! Thank you very much for your great help, again!!!